# Mongodb Mongoid inserting data speed up

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid3

I need to insert 2.000.000 rows of data into MongoDB, row by row but when it reaches 200.000 inserts it gets very slow, I am using Mongoid and I do not know if I can use bulk insert as I need data validation before inserting. How I can speed up this process?
Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For significant performance improvement, you should try batch insertion via `Moped::Collection#insert`.  You will have to explicitly call  `#valid?` yourself.  Try something like the following, assuming that `data_rows` is an array of Mongoid model `MyModel` objects.

```
slice_size = 1000    
data_rows.each_slice(slice_size) do |slice|
  slice.each{|data_row| raise "validation error" unless data_row.valid?}
  MyModel.collection.insert(slice.collect{|data_row| data_row.serializable_hash})
end
```

If you can intercept your import data in "raw" non-Mongoid model form, you can bypass some overhead by inserting arrays of hashes, but then you will have to program your own custom validations and not be able to use Mongoid model validation.